# Java array list returning 0 value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a class like this, which contains a bunch of arraylist as you can see. I've been setting the array with the methods add.. and then retrieving it with get.., when i tried to System.out.println numberofcitizen for example it is returning 0. Note that i have instantiated the class in another class to set the values.

```
public int numberOfCitizen;

private final ArrayList<Integer> citizenid = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<String> citizenName = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Integer> citizenWaste = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Float> longitude = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Float> latitude = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<>();

public void working() {
    System.out.println("executing fine");
}

public void setnoOfcit(int number) {
    this.numberOfCitizen = number;

}

public int getnumber() {
    return this.numberOfCitizen;
}

public void addCitizenId(int citizen) {
    citizenid.add(citizen);
}

public int getCitizenid(int i) {
    int citId = citizenid.get(i);
    return citId;
}

public void addCitizenName(String citizenname) {
    citizenName.add(citizenname);
}

public String getCitizenName(int i) {
    return citizenName.get(i);
}

public void addCitizenWaste(int waste) {
    citizenWaste.add(waste);
}

public int getCitizenWaste(int i) {
    return citizenWaste.get(i);
}

public void addLatitude(float lat) {
    latitude.add(lat);
}

public float getLat(int i) {
    return latitude.get(i);
}

public void addlng(float lng) {
    longitude.add(lng);
}

public float getlng(int i) {
    return longitude.get(i);
}

com.graphhopper.jsprit.core.problem.VehicleRoutingProblem.Builder vrpBuilder = com.graphhopper.jsprit.core.problem.VehicleRoutingProblem.Builder.newInstance();

public void runVPRSolver() {
    System.out.println(numberOfCitizen);
    System.out.println(getCitizenName(0));
    //create a loop to fill parameters
```

Comment: You never change the value of `numberOfCitizen`. I think you want to use `citizenid.size()` and possibly ommit `numberOfCitizen` all together. Also realize that you're now leaving the managing of the lists to the user of the class, which could potentially lead to behavior you don't want.

Comment: i did change it with the method setNoOfcit :(

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I seem to have missed the setter for `numberOfCitizen`, but this class just screams bad design as you are leaving a lot up to the user of the class

Comment: Can you show us where you call setoOfcit() method?

Answer (score 1):

## Probable source of problem :

`numberOfCitizen` is a member attribute that you seem to never change. If you want it to represent the number of elements in your lists, either use `citizenName.size()` or increment the value of `numberOfCitizen` in one of the add methods.

## Design flaw :

Your design takes for granted that your other class always use that one properly. Anytime you or someone uses that class, he must make sure that he add every single element manually. This adds code that could be grouped inside your class, which would be cleaner and easier to maintain.

So instead of several add method like this :

```
addCitizenid();
addCitizenName();
addCitizenWaste();
addLongitude();
addLatitude();
addAddress();
```

Design an other `Citizen` class which will contain those elements, and use a single list of instances of that class. That way you can use only one method :

```
private List<Citizen> citizenList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addCitizen(Citizen c) {
     /*Add element in your list*/
     citizenList.add(c);
}
```

This programming methodology is called *"Encapsulation"* which you can read about [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `numberOfCitizen` in your add methods. For example:

```
public void addCitizenId(int citizen){
    citizenid.add(citizen);
    numberOfCitizen++;
}
```

I would also suggest encapsulating your variables into Objects, so create a citizen class:

```
public class Citizen {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer name;
    private Integer waste;
}
```

And change your variable to an ArrayList of objects:

```
ArrayList<Citizen> citizens;
```

Comment: if `numberOfCitizen` is incremented in every add methods, you end up with `numberOfCitizen == ([actual number of citizen] * [number of added attributes per citizen])`